# Airflow heartbeat FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Has anyone encountered "sorry, too many clients already" error on heartbeat phase while running a subdag?

> [2017-11-22 08:21:23,747] {jobs.py:2136} ERROR - Exception while
>   trying to heartbeat! Sleeping for 5.0s Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 2131,
>   in _execute
>       self.heartbeat()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 180, in
>   heartbeat
>       job = session.query(BaseJob).filter(BaseJob.id == self.id).first()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2755, in first
>       ret = list(self[0:1])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2547, in **getitem**
>       return list(res)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2855, in **iter**
>       return self._execute_and_instances(context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2876, in _execute_and_instances
>       close_with_result=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2885, in _get_bind_args
>       **kw   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2867, in _connection_from_session
>       conn = self.session.connection(**kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 998, in connection
>       execution_options=execution_options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 1003, in _connection_for_bind
>       engine, execution_options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 403, in _connection_for_bind
>       conn = bind.contextual_connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2112, in contextual_connect
>       self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       e, dialect, self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
>       exc_info   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 203, in raise_from_cause
>       reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       return fn()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 387,
>   in connect
>       return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 766,
>   in _checkout
>       fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 516,
>   in checkout
>       rec = pool._do_get()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line
>   1229, in _do_get
>       return self._create_connection()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 333,
>   in _create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 461,
>   in **init**
>       self.**connect(first_connect_check=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 651,
>   in __connect
>       connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 105, in connect
>       return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 393, in connect
>       return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init**.py", line
>   130, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already

from airflow.cfg:
on airflow.cfg:

> sql_alchemy_pool_size = 100
>
> sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600

Is there a known solution to this problem? 
I'm using airflow 1.8.2 with LocalExecutor.

Comment: What is the max number of clients postgres is configured to allow? You can run `SHOW max_connections;` to find out.

Comment: It is configured to 100. Also, exception be is from SQL alchemy side, not from db side